# Parse query update or append based upon whereKey in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I want to check a class in Parse and check this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Score")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Bob")
query.whereKey("opponent", equalTo:"Jim")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects, error) -> Void in

if error == nil {
if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
  for object in objects {
    // if there is a match, update the record
      object["wins"] = 5
  }
} //else if there is no match on the whereKey, append the record to "Score" class.
} else {
// Log details of the failure
println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

There is a small example code of the basic functionality. I want to update if I find a match but insert it if it doesn't exist. I was trying something like this:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

         if error == nil {
              if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                     if objects == [] {
                        //println(objects)
                        }
                     for object in objects {
```

It isn't finding the objects but I'm not sure how to detect for that. There has to be a simple way to do this, does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: `if objects.count == 0`

Comment: That should work but is there anything within Parse to do this update/insert?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing can be achieved straight-fowardly if you break functions up into logical units.  Recognizing that each runs asynchronously, give each a completion block that looks like (maybe exactly like) the parse SDK blocks...

In your case, you want to find an object, creating it if it doesn't exist, and update and save it either way.  I'd do something like the following. (please note that I don't write swift, and have learned only enough here to get across the bigger idea):

```
// record that player named playerName won against opponent named opponent
func playerBeatOpponent(playerName: String, opponent: String, completion: (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    self.findOrCreateScore(playerName, opponent: opponent, completion: { (scoreObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let scoreObject = scoreObject {
            let wins = scoreObject["wins"] as! Int
            scoreObject["wins"] = wins + 1
            scoreObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(completion)
        }
    })
}

// answer a Score object recording a win between playerName and opponent
// find and return it if it exists, or create it if it doesn't exist
func findOrCreateScore(playerName: String, opponent: String, completion: (scoreObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    self.findScore(playerName, opponent: opponent, completion: { (scoreObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if scoreObject == nil {
            self.createScore(playerName, opponent: opponent, completion: completion)
        } else {
            completion(scoreObject: scoreObject, error: nil)
        }
    })
}

// find a score matching the criteria given
func findScore(playerName: String, opponent: String, completion: (scoreObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Score")
    query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:playerName)
    query.whereKey("opponent", equalTo:opponent)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let object: AnyObject = objects?[0] {
                completion(scoreObject:object as? PFObject, error: nil)
            } else {
                completion(scoreObject:nil, error: nil)
            }
        } else {
            completion(scoreObject:nil, error: error)
        }
    }
}


// create a new score object with the given params
func createScore(playerName: String, opponent: String, completion: (scoreObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var scoreObject = PFObject(className:"Score")
    scoreObject["playerName"] = playerName
    scoreObject["oponent"] = opponent
    scoreObject["wins"] = 1
    scoreObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            completion(scoreObject: scoreObject, error: nil)
        } else {
            completion(scoreObject: nil, error: error)
        }
    }
}
```